# How to put Google Map in a custom UIView

Tags: xcode, google-maps, uiview

I know this question has already been asked before, but none of the answers were really clear to me and I can't find good tutorial on Internet... So, I want to put Google maps in a different UIView from the principal one in order to be able to show my menu bar on top.

Here is my actual code :

```
#import "MapViewController.h"
#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>

@implementation MapViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:46.809885
                                                            longitude:-71.184556
                                                                 zoom:18];
    mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
    self.view = mapView;
    mapView.mapType = kGMSTypeHybrid;

}

@end
```

Actually, the map is all over the app. It already set the class of my UIView to GMSKMapView and made an outlet name mapView to link my UIView with the controller.

I use Xcode 4.6.2

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm using this code:

//header file

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *viewForMap;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet GMSMapView *mapView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet GMSCameraPosition *camera;
```

//implementation file

```
 self.camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:46.2220
                                          longitude:25.2330 zoom:5
                                            bearing:0
                                       viewingAngle:0
               ];

    self.mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:_viewForMap.bounds camera:_camera];
    self.mapView.delegate = self;

    [self.viewForMap addSubview:_mapView];
```

**UPD**

to change map type:

```
self.mapView.mapType = kGMSTypeHybrid; //kGMSTypeNormal kGMSTypeHybrid kGMSTypeSatellite kGMSTypeTerrain
```

to change again camera view:

```
_mapView.camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:newLat
                                                  longitude:newLong
                                                       zoom:1
                                                    bearing:0
                                               viewingAngle:0
                       ];
```

don't forget to add in header file:

```
<GMSMapViewDelegate>
```

Comment: It works, but I can't set the map type, the coordinates and the zoom. The map is always showing Europe in map type view and not zoomed at al... Any ideas why it is not working?

Comment: What?! Change camera for others coordinates, other zoom level, etc,

Comment: Glad to help... Pay it forward! :)

Answer (score 1):

First create outlet Of UIView

```
#import <GoogleMapsM4B/GoogleMaps.h>
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<GMSMapViewDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet GMSMapView *mapView;
```

Add This in .h File

Now add this in .m file in view didload method

```
self.mapView.myLocationEnabled = YES;
self.mapView.mapType = kGMSTypeNormal;
self.mapView.settings.compassButton = YES;
self.mapView.settings.myLocationButton = YES;
self.mapView.delegate = self;
```