# Frame Google Maps for IOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, subview, google-maps-sdk-ios

This is the code in my viewDidLoad method. I am trying to prevent the Google Maps display from taking up the whole screen, but this code isn't working. I do not want to have to make two separate UIViews to display so is there an easier way to do this.

```
GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:-33.86
                                                        longitude:151.20
                                                             zoom:6];
mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 400.0) camera:camera];
mapView_.myLocationEnabled = YES;
mapView_.delegate = self;
self.view = mapView_;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17086674/1702413

Answer (score 1):

In this way your `mapView_` is filling your `self.view`. You should add the `mapView` as a subview of `self.view` by using :

`[self.view addSubview: mapView_];`

This way `mapView_` will be a subview of your main view and will fill the frame you set to it.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you make **self.view = mapView_;**? You are practically replace self.view with mapview.

I believe you want to do this:-

```
[self.view addSubview:mapView_];
```

It is to add the mapView as the subview of self.view.